# Change values of dataframe based on values of groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe generated from the following code:

```
vote_mode = dataset.groupby(['ini_num','dep_parl_group'])['vote'].agg(lambda x: disambiguated_mode(x)).to_frame()
```

This gives me the a three-column dataframe (ini_num, dep_parl_group, vote) where vote is the most frequent label, like the following:

| ini_num | dep_parl_group | vote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | A | vot_in_favour |
|  | B | vot_against |
| 99 | A | vot_against |
|  | C | vot_in_favour |
|  | D | vot_against |

I would like to change the `vote` values of the `dataset` (dataframe from which the groupby was built) to match the groupby dataframe attributes. The `dataset` is as follows:

| ini_num | dep_parl_group | vote | **what I want** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | A | vot_in_favour | vot_in_favour |
| 12 | A | vot_in_favour | vot_in_favour |
| 12 | A | vot_against | vot_in_favour |
| 12 | B | vot_against | vot_against |
| 12 | B | vot_against | vot_against |
| 99 | A | vot_against | vot_against |
| 99 | A | vot_against | vot_against |
| 99 | A | vot_in_favour | vot_against |
| 99 | C | vot_in_favour | vot_in_favour |
| 99 | D | vot_against | vot_against |
| 99 | D | vot_against | vot_against |

Specifically, I would like to have the `vote` values of every entry of `dataset` to match the corresponding ones in entries where the `ini_num` and `dep_parl_group` match.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: look at using transform instead of agg `dataset.groupby(['ini_num','dep_parl_group'])['vote'].transform(lambda x: disambiguated_mode(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, here I substituted for disambiguated_mode:

```
dataset['vote_1'] = (dataset.groupby(['ini_num','dep_parl_group'])['vote']
                            .transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))
```

Output:

```
    ini_num dep_parl_group           vote    what I want         vote_1
0        12              A  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour
1        12              A  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour
2        12              A    vot_against  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour
3        12              B    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
4        12              B    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
5        99              A    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
6        99              A    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
7        99              A  vot_in_favour    vot_against    vot_against
8        99              C  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour  vot_in_favour
9        99              D    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
10       99              D    vot_against    vot_against    vot_against
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set index of the original dataframe to `['ini_num', 'dep_parl_group']`, then do a left join with `vote_mode`

```
dataset.set_index(['ini_num', 'dep_parl_group']).join(vote_mode, on=['ini_num', 'dep_parl_group'], lsuffix='_old', rsuffix='_new')
```